# How to get rid of error while creating ACS Namespace on Azure Service Bus with PS?

Tags: powershell, azure, azureservicebus

**Short story**: I get the following error when trying to create a namespace on Azure Service Bus using Azure Powershell (Run as Administrator):

> PS C:> New-AzureSBNamespace -Name mynewnamespace2 -Location "East US"
>   -CreateACSNamespace $true -Namespac New-AzureSBNamespace : Object reference not set to an instance of an object. At line:1 char:1
>   + New-AzureSBNamespace -Name mynewnamespace2 -Location "East US" -CreateACSNamespace $ ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [New-AzureSBNamespace], NullReferenceException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.ServiceBus.NewAzureSBNamespaceCommand

**Long story**: I created a first namespace in Azure Service Bus to use Relay in buffered mode (namespace=mynewnamespace). It works great except when you want to transfer a larger set of data. For this there is the streamed mode and I found this handy example (https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/How-to-send-a-large-c36ab70e), changed appropriate settings for namespace and credentials and ran the server part from the project and I get the error

> {"The remote name could not be resolved:
>   'mynewnamespace-sb.accesscontrol.windows.net'"}

because, of course, this ACS namespace does not exist. So I found out that I need to create the namespace the old fashioned way using PS, installed Azure CLI and run the commands below with the following result:

> For a list of all Azure cmdlets type 'get-help azure'.
>
> For a list of Windows Azure Pack cmdlets type 'Get-Command *wapack*'.
>
> PS C:> azure login
>
> info:   Executing command login
>
> |info:    To sign in, use a web
>   browser to open the page https://aka.ms/devicelogin. Enter the code EE226448L to
>   authenticate. If you're signing in as an Azure AD application, use the
>   --username and --password parameters.
>
> /info:    Added subscription Visual Studio Enterprise with MSDN info:    Setting subscription
>   "Visual Studio Enterprise with MSDN" as default
>
> - info:    login command OK
>
> PS C:> New-AzureSBNamespace -Name mynewnamespace2 -Location "East US" -CreateACSNamespace $true -NamespaceType Messaging
>
> WARNING: Microsoft Azure PowerShell collects data about how users use
>   PowerShell cmdlets and some pro encounter.  Microsoft uses this
>   information to improve our PowerShell cmdlets.  Participation is volu 
>   choose to participate your device automatically sends information to
>   Microsoft about how you use Azure Powershell.
>
> If you choose to participate, you can stop at any time by using Azure
>   PowerShell as follows:
>   1. Use the Disable-AzureDataCollection cmdlet to turn the feature Off. The cmdlet can be found in the AzureResourceManager module To disable
>   data collection: PS > Disable-AzureDataCollection
>
> If you choose to not participate, you can enable at any time by using
>   Azure PowerShell as follows:
>   1. Use the Enable-AzureDataCollection cmdlet to turn the feature On. The cmdlet can be found in the AzureResourceManager module To enable
>   data collection: PS > Enable-AzureDataCollection
>
> Select Y to enable data collection [Y/N]: WARNING: You choose not to
>   participate in Microsoft Azure PowerShell data collection. WARNING:
>   The setting profile has been saved to the following path
>   'C:\Users\PDube\AppData\Roaming\Windows Azure Powershell\AzureDataCollectionProfile.json'.
>
> New-AzureSBNamespace :
>   Object reference not set to an instance of an object. At line:1 char:1
>   + New-AzureSBNamespace -Name mynewnamespace2 -Location "East US" -CreateACSNamespace $ ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [New-AzureSBNamespace], NullReferenceException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.ServiceBus.NewAzureSBNamespaceCommand

I tried to create the new namespace using Azure CLI on 2 different computers, thinking the first install was corrupted, but I get the exact same error.

How can I fix this error?